# Python отправка email на gmail

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

Привет есть такой скрипт на python

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header

# Настройки
mail_sender = 'mail@gmail.com'
mail_receiver = 'mail@gmail.com'
username = 'mail@gmail.com'
password = '123fuckypu'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')

# Формируем тело письма
subject = u'Тестовый email от '
body = u'Отправка письма на Питтоне '
msg = MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')

# Отпавляем письмо
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(mail_sender, mail_receiver, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

на все другие почты работает(mail.ru,yandex,ru и т.д.), на на gmail выдает ошибку(хотя на gmail настроил авторизацию з мение безопазных приложений):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\f0st\Desktop\post.py", line 21, in <module>
    server.login(username, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 729, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
    smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvx\n5.7.14 gfl4heOeAD4f_iQHRXx-gPwNRGalRzc6UXknyTR4xAiAWK5KENf-Q0gfE5811Z-SqRn7Rq\n5.7.14 cukkiOrcc4Twik4nRwhlY5Gsh23mwu32lwuotv-WQAbGMDBlXIN7lIlf03wAwD4wQPyXNM\n5.7.14 A3XnnjwqoBLpd7LA8kjQHm3widA29l-S5QTm9MT4pvhJ-vkB9T7U7vhMF_oWYuJgKSW_fP\n5.7.14 87fJSF-abKA-ow3gruty4wTyATCdE> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 u30sm8540501wru.88 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: Вам же написали: Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.

Comment: Да я видел, но проблема в том что я авторизирован!

Comment: код уже как есть может работать, хотя лучше документированный интерфейс использовать и передавать host, port отдельно¶ Как @KAGGDesign уже сказал, сообщение об ошибке просит вас вручную зайти через браузер в вашу учётную запись и попробовать снова после этого.

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовал отправку так:

```
content = 'Это внутренности письма'
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('komp.lord@gmail.com','########не скажу')
mail.sendmail('komp.lord@gmail.com', 'komp.lord@gmail.com', content)
```